# Magento - sort/order the suggestions in the Autocomplete search form

Tags: magento

how can I change the sort/order in the suggestions of the Autocomplete search form.

I use Magento version 1.4.1.1

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it quick, copy /app/code/**core**/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Mysql4/Query/Collection.php into /app/code/**local**/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Mysql4/Query/Collection.php in local scope file find this line:

```
->order('popularity desc');
```

and replace it with this:

```
->order('query_text asc');
```

This is enough to make it work.

If you are interested in how does it work here you go.

1. form.mini.phtml sends request to `suggestAction` function of `Mage_CatalogSearch_AjaxController` though the following url: `http://www.yourdomain.com/catalogsearch/ajax/suggest?q=query` (may be quite useful for debugging).
2. Then instance of `Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Autocomplete` makes a query to database `catalogsearch_query` table through `getSuggestCollection` function call.
3. Inside this function the actual collection is built but for some reasons I was not able to apply to `setOrder` function to it so I had to dug one step deeper.
4. The clue lies in setQueryFilter function from the file you just copied above. Replacing the ordering method did the trick.

Hope it helped.